# MySQL insert syntax error in pre-written script

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

I'm using a modified version of a pre-written script. It works in other places on the site but I can't work out what I've missed here...

```
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO cmsportfolio (status,title,imgurl,imgthumb,section,url,`desc`,type) VALUES (".
    "'".$HTTP_POST_VARS['status']."', ".
     "'".$HTTP_POST_VARS['title']."', ".
    "'".addslashes($HTTP_POST_VARS['imgurl'])."', ".
    "'".addslashes($HTTP_POST_VARS['imgthumb'])."', ".
    "'".$HTTP_POST_VARS['section'].", ".
    "'".addslashes($HTTP_POST_VARS['url'])."', ".
    "'".addslashes($HTTP_POST_VARS['desc'])."', ".
    "'".$HTTP_POST_VARS['type']."' )";


if ($result = $connector->query($insertQuery)){

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=addsuccess');
    exit;

}else{
    echo "Error message = ".mysql_error(); 
    exit('<center>Sorry, there was an error saving to the database</center>');
}
```

I get the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk', 'frgdr tr tr', '0' )' at line 1
>   Sorry, there was an error saving to the database

(the error refers to the last 3 fields of the query)

Comment: Tip: Don't use `addslashes`, use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Do `echo $insertQuery`, check for stray apostrophes. Also note that you should escape everything coming from the form, and `mysql_real_escape_string()` is more secure than `addslashes()`.

Comment: Why are you escaping some variables and leaving some others unescaped ?

Comment: I love stackoverflow. I learn more from one one missing apostrophe here than weeks of reading tutorials and googling. Lesson learned. Escape everything with mysql_real_escape_string and build simple queries. Thanks all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 "'".$HTTP_POST_VARS['section'].", ".
```

Missing ending quote

Comment: Wow, i didn't spot that. *FACEPALM* Thanks!

Comment: And that, ladies and gentlemen, is why one doesn't construct queries in such ways.  _Because_ it's difficult to spot :)

Answer (score 2):

The only stupid mistake you've made is not posting the generated SQL.  The extremely unwise decision you've made is not escaping the POST parameters.  You got lucky in that you got a syntax error from a single quote in `title`, before some prankster decided to post `title='; drop table cmsportfolio; -- '`.  See [here](http://xkcd.com/327/).

**EDIT:** Sparky points out the typo that is causing your immediate problem.

Comment: Your totally right. The form in question is in my admin area which is secure, but it's a bad habit to get into. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: On that note. Is addslashes the correct mothod for doing so lately? Or should i be using real_escape_string??

Comment: IMHO, you should use neither, but instead use [prepared statements](http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/).

Answer (score 0):

i guess 'imgthunb' might have a single quote in it...